# How to zoom multiple windows at a time in OpenCV (like linkaxes in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, qt, opencv, zooming

Is there any way to zoom in one windows and other windows will zoom also in OpenCV (with Qt)? In another words, I need a way to do the same thing like the function linkaxes in Matlab. Do I have any chance?

Comment: Yes, it's feasible in Qt. You can connect the signal: mousewheel(zoom) to multiple slots(of different windows, ofc): replot. That's the way how Qt does it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are saying... Could you please be fore specific?